# React Bootstrap - the width off the progress bar is too small

Tags: reactjs, css-grid, react-bootstrap

I'm using React Bootstrap and CSS Grid. The progress bar is too small whenever I have it in a grid system but works perfectly somewhere else.
[image]

I don't know if the problem is from React bootstrap, or maybe CSS grid is hindering the width of the progress bar

[image]

Here is the source code. I feel like the width of the bar is directly proportional to the number of columns there are. If this is the case, then how do I merge the columns together to form just one?

```
// JSX
<div className="item2">
        <Combat />
      </div>
      <div className="item3 w-100">
        <p>Progressbar</p>
        <ProgressBar
          variant="length"
          now={increment}
          label={`${increment}`}
        />
        <p>{storeMoves}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="item4">details</div>
      <div className="item5">profile-left</div>
      <div className="item6">profile-right</div>
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={close}>
        Save Changes
      </Button>


CSS
.item1 {
  grid-area: image;
  height: 250px;
}
.item1 img {
  max-height: 80px;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: stats;
  height: 250px;
}
.item3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  grid-area: progressBar;
  height: 250px;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: details;
  height: 10px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "image image stats progressBar progressBar progressBar"
    "details details details details details details"
    "profile-left profile-left profile-left profile-right profile-right profile-right";
  grid-gap: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.grid-container > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: rgb(230, 228, 228);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the issue. I was styling the width of .progress-bar instead of .progress. After setting the width of .progress to 100%, I am now able to get the full width. 
[image]